# Assign event handler to method

Tags: c#, .net

how can I assign the Form closing event to the menustrip item click method ?

```
this.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(this.Form1_Closing);

private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  //
}


private void izlazToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to close the the Form in click event, so:

```
private void izlazToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

This will trigger `Closing` event.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there any way I can do something like this `this.menustripItem_click += new CancelEventHandler(this.Form1_Closing);`

Comment: Not really as those two events are of different type (type of `e` is different). If you want to run the same code in both of them, than you can extract it to a third method and call it from both event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could hook up the Close method to the Click event on your menu item is through the use of a lambda expression. The following code in the form's constructor demonstrates this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.izlazToolStripMenuItem.Click += (s, a) => this.Close();
}
```

More information on lambda expressions can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx